# get only the first appearance of the value from the column with groupby

Tags: pandas

existing dataframe :

```
ID       place    Date        count
22        zz   22-05-2022      2
22        zz   23-05-2022      2
22        zz   22-05-2022      2
11        aa   28-05-2022      1
11        aa   28-05-2022      1
```

expected dataframe :

```
ID       place    Date        count
22        zz   22-05-2022      2
22        zz   23-05-2022      -
22        zz   22-05-2022      -
11        aa   28-05-2022      1
11        aa   28-05-2022      -
```

score should appear only once in the score table

previous dataframe was achieved using the below code :

```
df['score'] = df.groupby(['ID'])['Date'].transform('nunique')
```

Comment: `df['score'] = df.groupby('id')['Date'].transform('nunique').mask(df.duplicated('ID'))`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way using `groupby()` and `head()`

```
df['count'] = df['count'].groupby(df['ID']).head(1)
```